# Can't access Bluetooth characteristic values using Windows UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth

I know this is simple, but just can't get it. I can read characteristics fine, but I can't access characteristic values. Here's the short amount of code attempting to do this. The *input* buffer content just reads as '{byte[0]}' instead of the value 0x1234 which is the programmed value and read by other BLE clients.

```
GattReadResult cVal = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync();
if (cVal.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
    try
    {
        var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(cVal.Value);
        var input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
        reader.ReadBytes(input);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes requires multiple read attempts in other clients such as nRF Connect to work. So, I put this routine in a button and can retry multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

It should depend on how you pass the data and whether you use cryptographic operations. Base on the official [BluetoothLE](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/BluetoothLE) and in the [Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs) code behind, the `CharacteristicReadButton_Click` method read the actual value.

```
 GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                string formattedResult = FormatValueByPresentation(result.Value, presentationFormat);
            }
```

There is the detaied code of `FormatValueByPresentation` method in the [Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs/Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs) code behind, you should be able to implement your reading value base on the code sample:

```
private string FormatValueByPresentation(IBuffer buffer, GattPresentationFormat format)
        {
            // BT_Code: For the purpose of this sample, this function converts only UInt32 and
            // UTF-8 buffers to readable text. It can be extended to support other formats if your app needs them.
            byte[] data;
            CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffer, out data);
            if (format != null)
            {
                if (format.FormatType == GattPresentationFormatTypes.UInt32 && data.Length >= 4)
                {
                    return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0).ToString();
                }
                else if (format.FormatType == GattPresentationFormatTypes.Utf8)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        return "(error: Invalid UTF-8 string)";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Add support for other format types as needed.
                    return "Unsupported format: " + CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString(buffer);
                }
            }
            else if (data != null)
            {
                // We don't know what format to use. Let's try some well-known profiles, or default back to UTF-8.
                if (selectedCharacteristic.Uuid.Equals(GattCharacteristicUuids.HeartRateMeasurement))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return "Heart Rate: " + ParseHeartRateValue(data).ToString();
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        return "Heart Rate: (unable to parse)";
                    }
                }
                else if (selectedCharacteristic.Uuid.Equals(GattCharacteristicUuids.BatteryLevel))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // battery level is encoded as a percentage value in the first byte according to
                        // https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.battery_level.xml
                        return "Battery Level: " + data[0].ToString() + "%";
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        return "Battery Level: (unable to parse)";
                    }
                }
                // This is our custom calc service Result UUID. Format it like an Int
                else if (selectedCharacteristic.Uuid.Equals(Constants.ResultCharacteristicUuid))
                {
                    return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0).ToString();
                }
                // No guarantees on if a characteristic is registered for notifications.
                else if (registeredCharacteristic != null)
                {
                    // This is our custom calc service Result UUID. Format it like an Int
                    if (registeredCharacteristic.Uuid.Equals(Constants.ResultCharacteristicUuid))
                    {
                        return BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0).ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return "Unknown format: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
                    }
                    catch (ArgumentException)
                    {
                        return "Unknown format";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "Empty data received";
            }
            return "Unknown format";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Breeze. Works like a charm!

Comment: Hi @michael meier if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.